# Why is same ASP.VB conditional written the same way behaving differently for 2 different number fields

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have an ASPX.VB script page to drive the selection of filter parameters for the web page - https://maldivescomplete.com/maldivesv/Room%20Types/RoomTypeSearch.aspx

Filtering on "Rating" works perfectly, but filtering on "Room Size" (constructed in exactly the same way) only works for the first two options an finds no records for the other 3.

Hoping I missing something terribly obvious that a more insightful ASP/VB person can spot quickly?

1. Select the range

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="RoomSize" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Value="20000000">Any</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="100">Less than 100</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="300">100 - 300</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="500">300 - 500</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="2000">More than 500</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

2. Identify the bottom number of the range with ASP.VB code to select the comparison numbers from the menu selections

```
    If Rating.SelectedIndex = 0 Or Rating.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
            e.Command.Parameters("Rating2").Value = 0
        Else
            e.Command.Parameters("Rating2").Value = Rating.Items(Rating.SelectedIndex - 1).Value
        End If
...

        If RoomSize.SelectedIndex = 0 Or RoomSize.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
            e.Command.Parameters("RoomSize2").Value = 0
        Else
            e.Command.Parameters("RoomSize2").Value = RoomSize.Items(RoomSize.SelectedIndex - 1).Value
        End If
```

3. Set control parameters

```
  <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="RoomSize" Name="CPRoomSize" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="RoomSize2" Type="Int32" />
```

4. Run filter Boolean (below part of larger expression obviously

@CPRoomSize > [Square Metres] AND @RoomSize2 <= [Square Meters]

I've tried a number of different variations to explore the behaviour, but I can't get the one filter to behave like the other.  All other aspects are the same (data type of the field, etc).

Comment: The code is going to do what the code does. Have you actually debugged the code, i.e. set breakpoints and stepped through it line by line? What EXACTLY happens that you don't expect or doesn't happen that you do expect?

Comment: Is room size a text or number type in the database? In text, then we would find that 400 > 2000!!!! (since character works alike alphabet - and A or Apple comes before B, and in number land as text, then 40 comes after 2500000. So, I would check your table design and data types.